# Not redirecting to home page (index.php)

Tags: php

Is there something wrong about my code? It works but its not redirecting to my index.php it always ended up in the login.php where the form is located.

```
    <?php
    include 'core/ini.php';

    if (empty($_POST) === false) {
        $username = $_POST ['username'];
        $password = $_POST ['password'];

        if (empty ($username) === true || empty ($password) === true ) {
            $errors[] = 'You need to enter a username and password!';

        } else if (user_exists($username) === false) {
            $errors[] = 'We can\'t find that username. Have you registered?';
        } else if (user_active($username) === false) {
            $errors[] = 'You haven\'t activated your account! ';
        } else {
            $login = login($username, $password) ;
            if ($login === false) {
                $errors[] = 'That username/password combination is incorrect ';
            } else {
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;
                header('Location :index.php');
                exit();
            }
        }
        print_r($errors);
    }
    ?>

thanks!

EDIT *

this is my login.php 
<?php
include 'core/ini.php';

if (empty($_POST) === false) {
    $username = $_POST ['username'];
    $password = $_POST ['password'];

    if (empty ($username) === true || empty ($password) === true ) {
        $errors[] = 'You need to enter a username and password!';

    } else if (user_exists($username) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'We can\'t find that username. Have you registered?';
    } else if (user_active($username) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'You haven\'t activated your account! ';
    } else {
        $login = login($username, $password) ;
        if ($login === false) {
            $errors[] = 'That username/password combination is incorrect ';
        } else {
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;
            header('Location :index.php');
            exit();
        }
    }
    print_r($errors);
}
?>
```

this is where the process go. I don't know where should I put my start session but I don't know why it works without having an error.

Comment: post your login() function, maybe you wrote something in this function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `header('Location :index.php');` to `header('Location: index.php');` That space might be the cause.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you missed the `session_start();` on top of the page since you are storing session. Initiate the `session_start();`.

Also does your `login()` function returns TRUE? Echo something to check whether the function returns TRUE as expected.

Comment: my session starts in here
`<?php
session_start();

require 'database/connect.php';
require 'functions/general.php';
require 'functions/users.php';

$errors = array ();
?>`

Comment: remove `exit();`, comment the `header()` part and do `echo "IN";` first to ensure that the function returns TRUE

Answer (score 0):

You hae to use `session_start` on top of page and I think you should remove `exit` after headerlocation..

Comment: my session starts in here `<?php session_start(); require 'database/connect.php'; require 'functions/general.php'; require 'functions/users.php'; $errors = array (); ?>`